# Spring is chekcing Authorization header when an endpoint is not required to be authenticated

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth-2.0, token

I'm building a Spring Boot app with Oauth2

This is my security filter chain bean

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) ->
                        oauth2.jwt((jwt) -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtToUserConverter))
                )
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                        .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler())
                );
        return http.build();
    }
```

All clients that call /api/auth/* don't need to be authenticated and clients that call any other endpoint yes.

I'm calling to the endpoint `/api/auth/login`

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
        Authentication authentication = daoAuthenticationProvider
                .authenticate(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .unauthenticated(loginDTO.getUsername(), loginDTO.getPassword()));

        log.error(headers.toString());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(tokenGenerator.createToken(authentication));
    }

}
```

When I not include the header **Authentication** in my request, all works as expected I get a JSON with the tokens.

When I include the header **Authentication** in my request, I got a HTTP 401 as response saying "invalid token". But to call that endpoint is not necessary to be authenticated as you can see in the security filter chain configuration.

This message is created by the BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint() class, configured in the security filter chain, which is called when an exception is throwed. This means that the request is not reaching the endpoint and Spring Security is intercepting it before and throwing an exception.

**EDIT**

If I set `.anyRequest().permitAll()`  I get the same result

**I know that I'm sending a bad token. But the thing is that I don't need Spring to check security on that endpoints because is not neccessary**

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advice!

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?": sending invalid authorization.

Comment: I know that I'm sending bad authorization but what I need is when I call that endpoints /api/auth/* Spring doesn't check auithorization because is not necessary. As you read, when I don`t include Authorization Header, all OK, if I include it, Spring throws exception

Comment: @ch4mp (I forgot to mention you, sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`permitAll()` grants access to anonymous requests, it does not deactivate security.

A simplistic model to understand your issue would be UAA:

- **A**uthentication is performed first in the chain.

  - if there is no authorization header and anonymous is enabled, then an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` is put in the security context
  - else if an authorization header is present **and valid**, then an instance of what your `jwtToUserConverter` returns is put in the security context
  - else an exception is thrown and a 401 is returned
- only if **U**ser **A**uthentication didn't throw is **A**uthorization performed: evaluation of `permitAll`, `hasAuthority`, etc against what is in the security context.

One option would be to exclude some of your endpoints from your "resource-server" security filter-chain, but I would not try to change this behavior: OAuth2 clients should be aware of tokens status and it should be really careful with who they communicate it too => **token validation should always succeed when a request is sent to a resource-server by a serious & honest client** (authorization may fail).

#### Side note

I am surprised with this `api/auth/**` end-points on a resource-server.

One of great OAuth2 improvements is to hide the user credentials from both clients and resource-servers. Only authorization-server should see it.

Your client should redirect the user to the authorization-server instead of collecting credentials and communicating it to a resource-server...

If you don't already, you should consider using a [client side OAuth2 library](https://openid.net/developers/certified/), this would save you quite some time (and reduce the risk to introduce security breaches)

This is just how OAuth2 works (nothing specific to Spring in the following) :

- **client** sends requests to consume REST resources. It is in charge of correctly authorizing requests it sends: provide with a valid access token in Authorization header (not expired, expected issuer, audience matching the server it sends this request to and if it's a JWT, valid signature).
- **resource-server** respond to those REST requests. It validates access tokens for that, either by himself with a JWT doder (only if tokens are JWt, of course) or by introspection on the authorization-server
- **authorization-server** is responsible for emitting tokens **to clients** within one of the standard flows. Those 3 are the most important ones:

  - authorization-code to authenticate a client on behalf of a user. This involves user login **on the authorization-server** (and this can be done silently under certain circumstances)
  - client-credential to authenticate a trusted programmatic client as itself (no user context)
  - refresh-token to issue a fresh access-token to an already authenticated client

Comment: I'm pretty new to Spring Security so I didn't understand well your comment. Oauth2 client should be aware of tokenss what it means? Clients should add that header only  when necessary?
Your side note, authorization server is anotyher backend that its only purpose is to verify authentication? How to do this? I really apreciate your help!! @ch4mp

Comment: Client should set that header only when required and only when valid (not expired and right audience). Authorization server is a backend either on your servers (Keycloak for instance) or in the cloud (Okta, Auth0 and Cognito are just samples among many). I edited my answer to add OAuth2 actors responsibilities, but honestly, you need more OAuth2 background before rushing into implementing it...